Dataclass Enum init item from another item
I'm trying to make an Enum the values of which are of a type which is a dataclass. As per the official Python Enum HOWTO, this can be achieved by inheriting from both Enum and the base dataclass.
Ok, so far, so good.
Now, because the underlying dataclass has quite a lot of fields, and the Enum values have only slight modifications between each other, I'd like to specify one of the values as a copy of another, but with a few select parameters changed. That's why I thought I'd use dataclasses.replace, but that doesn't work.
Here's a minimal reproduction code:
import dataclasses
from enum import Enum
from typing import ClassVar

@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
    s1: str
    s2: str

class B(A, Enum):
    b1: ClassVar[B] = 'b11', 'b12'
    b2: ClassVar[B] = dataclasses.replace(b1, s2='b22')

This throws this error on the last line:
TypeError: replace() should be called on dataclass instances

and, as I can see, it's because at the time b2 is instantiated, b1 is still just a tuple. Even if b1 would be properly initialized, because dataclasses.replace internally calls b1.__class__(b1=b1.s1, b2='b22'), this might fail as well because directly instantiating an Enum is not generally allowed, and I'm not sure how dataclass.replace would interfere with the mechanism that only allows instantiation inside class def.
Until now I was thinking to use something like astuple to pass the params of b1 to b2, but it's pretty unreadable to use code that changes the correct positional argument.
So, any ideas on how to make this work in readable and pythonic manner?
Note: I'm using Python version 3.9, also tried 3.12, but to no avail.

Does your dataclass have to be one? NamedTuple is arguably a more ergonomic choice in this specific situation.

Is there a reason the Enum has to derive from a dataclass rather than just having dataclass instances as values? Per the Enum documentation "Member values can be anything", including dataclass instances. Either way, if your slight variations are predictable/derivable, you could potentially override _generate_next_value_  in the Enum class, and then use auto for the values of your Enum members.

@InSync, in my particular use case (which is more complex than the example above - I've simplified it to a bare minimum necessary for reproduction), the base dataclass includes some behavior, as well.

@couteau, you're right, in this case I have just dropped the idea of subclassing, and made it work that way. But then, why would anyone want to derive from Enums and add mixins in the first place? Perhaps the semantics are clearer when one doesn't have to access .value all the time?
